# What exactly does get function return in R

Tags: r, get

exp <- get(name1[1])

exp

```
 -0.075         3            0.58

-0.045        40            7.78

-0.015       200           38.91

0.015       230           44.75

0.045        36            7.00

 0.075         5            0.97
```

But when is use **exp[][1]**, it returns only one value -0.075.

It should return entire column, but why is this happening?

Can some one help me out

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say since your example's not reproducible, but in general:

Get returns a single object given by the character you fed it as an argument.  So if `name1[1]` is set to `"myMatrix"` then it will return the contents of the `myMatrix` matrix.

If you want more than one object, use `mget`.